# Нахождение e^x с помощью суммы ряда даёт большую погрешность для отрицательных x

Tags: c#, алгоритм, ряды

Господа, нужна помощь по понимаю задачи вычисления суммы ряда с определенной точностью.

Насколько я понимаю, последнее слагаемое ряда не должно превышать точность.

Алгоритм, приведенный ниже, показывает очень похожий на правду результат с положительными иксами, но как дело доходит до отрицательных, сумма ряда может сильно отличаться от оригинального значения экспоненты в данной степени.

Для подтверждения того, о чем я говорю, приведу пару примеров.

Вопрос: такое сильное отличие при работе с отрицательными степенями экспоненты - это нормально или это косяк алгоритма? (Во втором примере сумма ряда вообще отрицательная, хотя экспонента ограничена снизу нулем).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double eps, x, i = 1, sum = 0, addend = 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Введите x.");
    x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Введите eps.");
    eps = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    while (Math.Abs(addend) > eps)
    {
        sum += addend;
        addend = addend * x / i;
        ++i;
    } 
    sum += addend;
    Console.WriteLine("Значение суммы ряда функции exp(x) в точке " + x + " с точностью " + eps + " равно " + sum);
    Console.WriteLine("Точное значение равно " + Math.Exp(x));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Пример 1 (запуск с положительным значением икса):

> Введите x.
>
> 16
>
> Введите eps.
>
> 0,000001
>
> Значение суммы ряда функции exp(x) в точке 16 с точностью 1E-06 равно
>   8886110,52050769
>
> Точное значение равно 8886110,52050787

Пример 2 (запуск с отрицательным значением икса):

> Введите x.
>
> -13
>
> Введите eps.
>
> 0,1
>
> Значение суммы ряда функции exp(x) в точке -13 с точностью 0,1 равно 
>   -0,0251088977651358
>
> Точное значение равно 2,26032940698105E-06

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cмотрите. Вы пытаетесь вычислить значение `2.26*10^-6` с точностью `0.1`. Естественно, Ваш цикл останавливается гораздо раньше, чем значение приближается к точному. Выводите значения `addend` и `sum` на каждой итерации, и Вы увидите, в чем дело.

Вы можете задавать не абсолютную, a относительную точность - размер очередного члена ряда относительно текущего значения суммы.

Comment: Так и думал, ибо при сильном уменьшении точности оно становилось более похожим на правду, но решил уточнить. В любом случае, большое спасибо за ответ.)

Comment: @lev83 Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.